# How can I simulate multiple specified calculation times in a multi-threaded environment?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to simulate hundreds of calculations of let's say 100ms each in a multi-threaded environment.

Say 400 calculations of 100ms on a quad core processor (i5-3570K) should take 10s. (400/4) * 100ms.

First attempt is of course Thread.Sleep(100), but in a multi-threaded environment, this gives opportunity to other threads to do their work (which is just sleeping). But I want to keep the processor busy for 100ms, without this passing opportunity.

Second attempt was to put a lock on the current thread before doing the sleep, but that seems not to work either. Calculation time is still only 3 seconds.

I have created a test class to simulate this, but apparently I need something better than the lock on the current thread, and still I would like to specify the calculation time. Any suggestions? Can I expect desired results from different locking mechanisms?

Or should I have different expectations? CPU Utilization is low, but I don't mind/did expect that.

Here's the source code for a unit test class that I used as prototype.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalculationTimeSimulator
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CalculationTimeTests
    {
        public int CalculateMeaningOfTheUniverse()
        {
            var thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

            lock (thread)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            return 42;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SubtleDouglasAdamsReferenceTest()
        {
            var theAnswerTo = CalculateMeaningOfTheUniverse();

            Assert.AreEqual(42, theAnswerTo);
            // Takes 103 ms, as expected with small overhead.
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TryIt400Times()
        {
            var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 400);

            Parallel.ForEach<int>(items, item =>
            {
                var theAnswerTo = CalculateMeaningOfTheUniverse();

                Assert.AreEqual(42, theAnswerTo);
            });
            // Took 3 sec, but I expected 10 sec on quad core processor.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of sleeping, try working for 100ms (while 100ms had yet to go by, do nothing)

Comment: A SpinLock might prove useful. When a 100ms thread start, have a lock created + locked, and the spinLock wait 100ms max.

Comment: SpinLock works unfortunately better than expected. It locks all threads, though I only want the currentThread to be locked. So now it takes 40 seconds, but I do want to allow multi core processing